# Issue addressing MODBUS via RS485 and PHP on Windows

Tags: windows-10, php, modbus, rs485

I have a USB to RS485 adapter connected to an RS485 relay board which I am able to correctly address using some software called sscom. Via sscom I can enable/disable the relays on the relay board. So I know both the USB->RS485 adapter and the RS485 relay board both work correctly.

I am trying to now do this via PHP so I have PHP installed on a Windows (10) PC, the same PC that the USB adapter is connected to and I've downloaded this https://github.com/toggio/PhpSerialModbus to try and get this working via PHP CLI.

When trying to run it I am getting 'Device must be opened to read it' which seems informative enough so I have gone to this line of the PHP code:

```
$modbus->deviceInit('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200,'none',8,1,'none');
```

And assume that I have the wrong info for the device in question. My device is on COM7 (as configured and working in sscom software).

In Windows, if I run this command:

```
reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
```

I get:

```
 \Device\VCP2    REG_SZ    COM7
```

My question is, what syntax do I need to use in the deviceInit line so that it looks at this device in the PHP code? I have tried all kinds of combinations, but none of them work and I always get the error indicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
class rapidserial{
  function _blocking($device,$mode){
      stream_set_blocking($device, $mode);
      return true;
     }
  }

$rapidserial = new rapidserial();
$device = "COM9";
exec("mode $device BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 xon=off octs=off rts=on");
$comport = fopen($device, "r+b");
if ($comport === false){
    die("Failed opening com port<br/>");
}else{
    echo "Com Port Open<br/>";
}

//Set non-blocking mode for writing
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,0);

$atcmd = "AT+\r";
fputs($comport, $atcmd);
usleep(200000);
 // Set blocking mode for reading
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,1);
echo '<br/>Response:<br/><br/>';
$res = fgets($comport, 4017);
fclose($comport);
echo $res."<br/><br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, appreciate your response.

After changing some file permissions I get a 'Com Port Open' response and the RS485 device LED flickers so I'm confident that it's connecting now, do you know how I then send the data to it? 

For example, I need to send 01 05 00 01 55 00 A3 5A to the device to activate a relay on the board. I have tried adding that line to the $atcmd variable, but it doesn't seem to work. 

Also the $res seems to be empty. 

Thanks for any further assistance, I'm totally new to ModBUS and RS485.

Comment: I am a little rusty with my modbus commands, I assume that is a write to the registry?

I would suggest using putty to get the write seq first.  Some modbus devices require a AT+ command first to initalise it, before recieving read/write commands.

With that said, if you need to send that command try setting $atcmd to "\x01\x05\x00\x01\x55\x00\xA3\x5A"

Keep in mind also I have used r+b to open the comport, so that means we are writing to the port in binary, that should be right, but if you get stuck, try and remove the b after the r+ in $comport = fopen($device, "r+b");

Comment: I also found this tool from USR - https://www.pusr.com/support/download/PC-Test-Software-USR-TCP232-Test-V1-3.html

and this program on github - https://github.com/ClassicDIY/ModbusTool

useful when I was learning modbus and how it all worked.  removes some of the formatting/timing/polling issues. Once you know the flow, then you can get it right with php etc.

Comment: Thanks, this worked "\x01\x05\x00\x01\x55\x00\xA3\x5A"

Really appreciate your help on this, many thanks for taking the time to reply and help.

Comment: No worries, happy to help.